# Java import statement syntax

Tags: java, import

This is a simple question, but I am really bugged by it. I was trying to find a duplicate, and googled it, but I was more surprised when I couldn't find a satisfying answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

In this statement `.Scanner` is the class,

`.util` is the name of the package

What is `java` or `javax` or whatever would stand before the first period in general?

UPDATE:

I also found this picture:

http://www.javatpoint.com/package

Is it true?

Comment: `java.util` is the name of the package.

Comment: Java or javax are also parts of the package name.

Comment: and whole 'java.util.Scanner' is a fully qualified class name :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [JLS 7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.1):

> The members of a package are its subpackages and all the top level class types (§7.6, §8) and top level interface types (§9) declared in all the compilation units (§7.3) of the package.
>
> For example, in the Java SE platform API:
>
> - The package java has subpackages awt, applet, io, lang, net, and util, but no compilation units.
> - The package java.awt has a subpackage named image, as well as a number of compilation units containing declarations of class and interface types.
>
> If the fully qualified name (§6.7) of a package is P, and Q is a subpackage of P, then P.Q is the fully qualified name of the subpackage, and furthermore denotes a package.

So you can glean from that:

- `java` is a package with no classes, only subpackages.
- `util` is a subpackage of `java` whose fully qualified name is `java.util`.
- `util` does not denote a package, `java.util` does.

*"I also found this picture: ... Is it true?"*

Yes, `util` is a subpackage of `java`. However, `util` is not a package. `java.util` is a package.

You can *think of* packages as a directory structure, if you wish, where each subpackage is a folder inside its outer package. So there would be a "folder" java and, inside that, another "folder" util. A package is denoted by its fully qualified name ("full path") so `java` is a package and `java/util` is a package. `/util` is not a package. But packages represented by a directory structure is not a spec. It is only a common implementation. It is up to the host system to decide how packages are stored ([JLS 7.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.2)).

Comment: Beware: Java doesn't actually have a package hierarchy. It looks like it because you define packages as subdirectories, so `util` is "inside" `java`, but `java` and `java.util` behave like completely independent packages.

Comment: @Darkhogg Yes, it's true, there is nothing in the spec that says a "subpackage" is at all related to its "containing" packages. For example, if `P` is a package and `P.Q` is a package that doesn't mean some class `P.Q.SomeClass` can use another class `P.AnotherClass`  by its simple name without an import or access its package-private/protected members and vice-versa. Though according to the spec `Q` is a member of `P`.

Answer (score 5):

Classes in Java are identified by a *fully qualified name* consisting in a concatenation of the package of the class and the name of the class (and any outer classes, if any). In general, in an import statement like:

```
import foo.bar.baz.MyClass;
```

everything except the last dot-separated field is the package name (`foo.bar.baz`) and the last field is the class name (`MyClass`). In your example, `java.util` is the package name and `Scanner` is the class name.

The process is actually a bit more complicated, as inner/nested classes and interfaces may be involved, but you get the idea.

Comment: So would it be true to say that everything before the actual class name is a subset of directories where the class is looked for? And java or whatever stands first is just one of the top-level directories for the  compiler to look into in its search of the necessary class?

Comment: @user3081519 It is commonly implemented as a directory structure but according to the JLS it doesn't have to be. It is "up to the host system".

Answer (score 1):

`import java.util.Scanner` says.

1. Look in the package java.
2. Within that look in the package util.
3. Within that find the class Scanner.
4. Now whenever we use the name of a class/etc within this java file (for example `Scanner s = new Scanner()`) then the class found by the import will be used.

Alternatively you could not do the import and do `java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner()` but you can see how that would quickly become unwieldy, especially if you use it in a lot of places within your file. Imports are just a handy way to reduce repeatedly specifying which version of the `Scanner` class you mean when you refer to `Scanner`.

Comment: This is not correct; packages do not nest. There is only a package "java.util"; there's no "util" or "java".

Comment: In your project view they are nested. In the filing system they are nested. In the JAR file they are nested...

Comment: You say they are not nested, I say that while they may not be defined as nested to all intents and purposes and for easy understanding they do nest. I'm also not aware of anything officially saying they don't although am willing to believe it exists and I don't know about it if someone can show me a link :)

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- the package name is `java.util`, not `util`. "java" is just part of the package name.
- package names are any series of valid java identifiers separated by dots, `AbC123.XYZ.foo` is a valid package name
- package may be omitted. If absent, the class is in the root directory of the project (I once worked on a project in production that had no packages! Everything was in one directory... Yikes!)
- by convention, packages starting with `java` are part of the JDK (plus extensions). There is nothing in the language that specifies this or enforces it

Answer (score 1):

`java` and `util` are names of nested packages. `java.util` is a path to final package.

They are directories inside `rt.jar` file.

`rt.jar` file is a `zip` archive, you can view it with `7-zip` program.

`Scanner` is a `Scanner.class` file inside `java/util` directory inside `rt.jar`

`import java.util.Scanner` directive just allows you to use `Scanner` class name in code without specifying full path to it.

`import java.util.*` directive allows you to use ALL class names in `java.util` without a path.

`import static java.util.Scanner.*` directive allows you to use ALL static members inside `Scanner`, without a paths. But there are none.

List of all packages in JRE are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

1) java is a package. (also represents a folder in file system).
It is directly in the classpath, so it is referenced by your program as 'java'. (subfolder in java folder)
2) util is a package inside java package (hence referenced as 'java.util').
3) Scanner is a class inside util package (hence 'java.util.Scanner')

---

You can have as many nested packages as you want like 'mypackage1.mypackage2.mypackage3. ...' and so on, as long as mypackage1 is in the classpath.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

the import statement represent a hierarchy

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

- `java` is the package
- `util` is the subpackage (inside java)
- `Scanner` is the class (inside util)

  import java.util.*;

The class name could be subtituited with an asterisk,
and that means import **all classes** in the mentioned subpackage.