# Importing Java classes run-time and compilation

Tags: java, import

Could someone explain what importing `java.net.*` imports? Also could someone explain briefly how importing say `java.swing.*` would affect the run-time and compilation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java import statement syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777260/java-import-statement-syntax)

Comment: You can refer [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2)

Comment: @TAsk: no, it does not seem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing a package, class, or any class member simply makes it possible to use that component's Simple Name instead of needing to use its Fully Qualified name. It doesn't affect runtime. It is a compilation feature. So instead of having to write

```
java.net.URL url = ...
```

you could simply write

```
URL url = ...
```

it won't affect performance or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.*` will import all classes of the `java.net` package. `java.swing.*` should have little affect on run-time and compilation because it is written entirely in Java and follows standard class hierarchy rules.